# Should we rename [mapping-by-code] to [nhibernate-mapping-by-code]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

Tag info for [mapping-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapping-by-code) says:

> Mapping-by-code is NHibernate's own API by which mappings can be configured by code. Introduced in NHibernate version 3.2.

With this, it is clear that this tag was specifically created for NHibernate's "Mapping-By-Code" feature. I broadly reviewed questions tagged with this tag; it appears that those are related to this feature of NHibernate and also tagged with [nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate).

There are also some other tags for specific features of NHibernate like [fluent-nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluent-nhibernate), [nhibernate-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-mapping) etc.

Please note that [nhibernate-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-mapping) and [mapping-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapping-by-code) represent two different features. Earlier implements mapping through XML files while latter one implements it through code.

Should we rename [mapping-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapping-by-code) to [nhibernate-mapping-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-mapping-by-code)?

Comment: I only found one question tagged [mapping-by-code] not related to NHibernate: [this entity-framework question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094694/how-can-i-avoid-using-microsoft-custom-tools-that-generate-code-for-entity-frame). Other than that one, looks like all the [mapping-by-code] questions are about NHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done; [mapping-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapping-by-code) has been renamed to and synonymized with [nhibernate-mapping-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-mapping-by-code).

With thanks to a preliminary review conducted by Nathan Mills (and apparently confirmed by Peter Cibulskis), [the one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094694/how-can-i-avoid-using-microsoft-custom-tools-that-generate-code-for-entity-frame) that was tagged [mapping-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapping-by-code) but wasn't about NHibernate has been edited to remove the tag (and also closed).

Answer (score 0):

156 [mapping-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapping-by-code) - 156 questions.
155 of those questions are about [nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate).

They are exactly the same.
[mapping-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapping-by-code) should be changed to [nhibernate-mapping-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-mapping-by-code).